# viewpager transform is lagging

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I got a view pager with only to fragment I use this code for transform animation

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {

        @Override
        public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
            final float normalizedposition = Math.abs(Math.abs(position) - 1);
            page.setAlpha(normalizedposition);
            page.setScaleX(normalizedposition / 2 + 0.5f);
            page.setScaleY(normalizedposition / 2 + 0.5f);
            page.setRotationY(position * -10);
        }
    });
```

but what I don't understand why my application lag while transfer from fragment to fragment

what can I do to increase the performance of transaction 
BTW I use a real device with 1 G ram for testing

thanks in advance

Comment: THis lag happens only in debug mode? Which device are you using?

Comment: nexus 7 with 600 m free
so u suggest that i install apk directly ??

Comment: Sometimes debugging mode it's very slower, in that case removing the USB cable its enough